# Calculating Hours by Dividing Total Seconds by 3600

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate the total hours worked when the shift end time passes to the next day.

`tHours` is not right. The expected result should be 12 however it is coming out as 11.

sShift = 08:00 PM (Start Shift)

eShift = 08:00 AM (End Shift)  -> next day

```vb
Time1 = CDate(sShift.Text)
Time2 = CDate(eShift.Text)
                    
If (Time2 <= Time1) Then
    Total_Seconds = (Time2 + 1 - Time1) * 24 * 3600
Else
    Total_Seconds = (Time2 - Time1) * 24 * 3600
End If

tMins = Int((Total_Seconds Mod 3600) / 60)

tHours = Int(Total_Seconds / 3600)
```

The `Total_Seconds` 43200, when divided by 3600 should result in 12. However  `tHours` is showing 11.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: My guess is that this is a floating point error.  `total_seconds = 43200` and `tHours = Int(total_seconds / 3600)` returns 12

Comment: Floating point error.  Declare your variables and data types properly and you should be OK (eg times=>`Date`; hrs/min/secs as `Long`)

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: I do not think that this will fix the floating point issue. My suggestion in this case would be to convert total_seconds to a long value after the calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely caused by a floating point error. This [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel) sheds some light on that.

My suggestion to fix your calculation in this case would be to use

```
If (time2 <= time1) Then
    total_seconds = (time2 + 1 - time1) * 24 * 3600
Else
    total_seconds = (time2 - time1) * 24 * 3600
End If
total_seconds = CLng(total_seconds)
```

And it is also good practise to use `Option Explicit`.